# MySQL update if the person exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

what would the MySQL query be to update a record if the record exists in the table i'm trying to update.

so for instance, i'm trying to set a certain column to blank if the record is in the table.  if the record is not in the table, i just don't want it to do anything.

i'm using php and mysql

Comment: What makes the record unique in the table?

Comment: Why not just try to update the record... if it doesn't exist, there won't be any error, just 0 records updated.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: If you are some database abstraction frameworks, I'd be careful with checking for 0 rows updated meaning that the record didn't exist. I've ran into issues with Drupal specifically where it would return 0 rows updated because it checked if the record needed to update, saw that it didn't, so it returned 0.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need some sort of unique identifier for the record. This can be a PRIMARY KEY, a UNIQUE constraint, or similar. Let's say your users have a `username` that is guaranteed to be unique.

You can constrain your `UPDATE` query to only affect rows that have that username. So if the username doesn't exist, nothing will be done.

```
UPDATE `tbl_users` SET `target_field` = NULL WHERE `username` = "joebloggs";
```

Comment: ooo ok, i wasn't sure if there was a better way to do it than just letting it fail.  my unique id is a guid.
thanks Interrobang

Comment: It won't fail, the query will succeed just fine. Just because the query updated no rows does not mean that it failed. Failed queries have invalid syntax or incorrect column names, for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can look for the id of the existsing record and update that like this :

```
Update tbl_name set field_name=new_data 
where id_column = (select id_column from tbl_name where key_column=key_value)
```